# a question for admob Count clicks in vpn app

Tags: android, admob, vpn, openvpn

I want to make a VPN app and a have a question.
Does Admob count VPN IP clicks? With too many users on one ip can I use Admob ads in my app?

Comment: did you making your VPN, I want to make a VPN application too, can you help me with ads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes admob count those clicks. But your cpc will be very low because ad serving will be poor when user uses vpn ip, that means admob serves random ads instead of targeted ads.So conversion rate will be very low. And one more thing is that ,if many users connected with same vpn server, they will be assigned same ip address so many clicks from same ip will be done. So there is a possibility of suspension of admob account. Its better to switch other ad networks available.

Comment: what would you suggest for alternative ad network?

Answer (score 0):

Admob strictly prohibited invalid clicks. 
You may refer to admob policy. They have strict system to detect clicks done by the use of vpn app. 
So, basically not. It will lead to your admob account permanent disabled.

Comment: no i don't want to fake click or like this . i want to use admob in my vpn app and i want to know when users use vpn . user click on admob banner is count or not ?

Comment: I also want to develop a vpn app since long.. can u help me out with it ☺️